# Why function overloading causes no ambiguous error? ( c++ )

Tags: c++, function, overloading, implicit-conversion

This code compiles without an error in gcc 4.6.1 and 4.8.1 ( eclipse auto compilation says: Candidates are: float pow(float, int) long double pow(long double, 
 int) double pow(double, int) ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    const int i = 0, x = 2;
    double y = pow( i, x );
    y = log( i ) / log( x );
    cout << y;
return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much. This code has performed some nice confusing at work. The compiler can be trusted?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: When in doubt, trust the compiler and forget eclipse

Comment: What is the (intermediate) goal of your program, to please eclipse, or to be compiled?

Comment: The goal of this program is to understand the implicit conversion. Of course is only a absurd simplification of a concrete problem. I found it hyperbolic to post thousand lines of code. The question is: Why get this code compiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not get any compilation errors, since the C++ standards says that your integer type is to be accepted and converted to double.

From the standard §26.8/11:

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>   [...]
>   3. Otherwise, if any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, then all arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to double.

Also see [cppreference.com/.../pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) where it says:

> If any argument has integral type, it is cast to double.

Comment: I believe this is actually the subject of a Defect Report.

Comment: @BenVoigt You mean in eclipse?

Comment: No, I mean the rule.  Actually implementing it turned out to be an unmaintainable template disaster, if I understand correctly.  Also very unintuitive, because the rules weren't consistent with the normal built-in conversions.

Comment: That's right and probably also the reason why questions like this arise.

Comment: Oh, now I think I remember.  Because following the rule requires templates to actually implement, it becomes a perfect match to user-defined types, and user-defined conversion operators aren't called correctly.

Comment: @BenVoigt - that rule is taken from C99's type-generic math (`tgmath.h`). It's not **that** hard to implement in C++; just lots of overloads.

Comment: @PeteBecker: But the rule is BAD for C++.  It's written for a language that doesn't have user-defined conversions.

Comment: @BenVoigt - it does **not** require templates to implement, just lots of overloads (which is what the rule says). If a user-defined type has a conversion to `int` and a conversion to `double` it's going to have a host of problems completely unrelated to this particular rule.

Comment: @PeteBecker: If a user-defined type has a conversion to `double` (and no other conversions), this rule truncates it to `float`.  In fact, any argument of any user-defined type is sent to the `float` overload (that requires templates to accomplish, and is quite ugly).  I'm not disagreeing with Pixelchemist's application of the rule to this specific case; I'm just pointing out it is the subject of a Defect Report and the rule is expected to change.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I wasn't aware of that issue, and assuming you're correct, that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the question is: "Why does function overloading cause ambiguity error?".

The answer is very clear in your case: There is not any version of pow(a, b) that accepts the parameter a as integer. Rather than displaying an error, the compiler tries to find a version of pow where there is a built-in (or custom) type conversion operator that can cast int into the type pow expects. It happens that there are 3 such functions and there is a conversion operator for each such function. That is why the compiler finds it ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Because `pow` acceptes a `double` or a `float` as second parameter (your `x`). [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) is the description for `pow` in C++11.

If your run the same code on VS2010 in will too issue an error.